# how to get upgraded org.jboss.as.jmx:main in WildFly10

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, wildfly-10

I am trying to upgrade my application from JBoss 7 to WildFly10, and I am getting a warning:

```
[0m[33m13:53:36,641 WARN [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) 
WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.mywar.war" is using a private module 
("org.jboss.as.jmx:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions 
without notice.
```

The module is mentioned in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure  >
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

how is called the new module for jmx? I tried to replace that with `org.jboss.remoting-jmx` but then I got

```
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is javax.management.JMRuntimeException: 
Failed to load MBeanServerBuilder class org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to WildFly forum it means nothing, see quote ([source](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/271649?sr=inbox&ru=9970))

> You got warning message as you are using internal "non-public" modules
>   from application server. Which just tells you that you should be
>   careful with this.